# Converting generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, type-conversion

I have two generic classes implementing one interface.

```
public interface Interface1
{
    //implementation
}
public interface Interface2<T>
{
    //implementation
}
class Class1<T>: Interface2<T> where T : Interface1
{
    //implementation
}
class Class2<T>: Interface2<T>
{
    //implementation
}
```

I would like to write a method that returns object of one of these classes, depending on the type T.

```
 Interface2<T> GetObject<T>()
{
    if (typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        //error
        return new Class1<T>();
    }
    return new Class2<T>();
}
```

Implementation of Class1 must be limited to types implementing interface. Is there a way to convert type T to Interface1? Now I am obtaining error: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Class1'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'Test.Interface1'.

Comment: Can't you use multiple overloads of the method GetObject.  Interface<Class1<T>>  GetObject<Class1<T>>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full reflection would be:

```
return (Interface2<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Class1<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
```

but it is slow (slow compared to doing a `new Foo()`)... I don't find any other way. Note that you are already going partially in the reflection direction (the `IsAssignableFrom`)

Mmmh using the "caching" of static classes, we can cheat a little... We can produce at runtime the exact code needed for creating a `new Class1<T>` and cache it.

First version

```
static class Maker<T>
{
    public static Func<Interface2<T>> Func { get; private set; }

    public static Interface2<T> New()
    {
        if (Func == null)
        {
            Func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Interface2<T>>>(Expression.New(typeof(Class1<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)))).Compile();
        }

        return Func();
    }
}
```

I use an expression tree that does the `new Class1<T>`. Then:

```
static Interface2<T> GetObject<T>()
{
    if (typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        return Maker<T>.New();
    }
    return new Class2<T>();
}
```

But still we can do something more. Given a type `T`, the result of the `if` in `GetObject()` can be precalculated and cached. We move the whole `GetObject()` inside the expression tree.

```
static class Maker2<T>
{
    public static Func<Interface2<T>> Func { get; private set; }

    public static Interface2<T> New()
    {
        if (Func == null)
        {
            if (typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                Func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Interface2<T>>>(Expression.New(typeof(Class1<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)))).Compile();
            }
            else
            {
                Func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Interface2<T>>>(Expression.New(typeof(Class2<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)))).Compile();
            }
        }

        return Func();
    }
}
```

and then

```
static Interface2<T> GetObject2<T>()
{
    return Maker2<T>.New();
}
```

The solution that uses an expression tree is very slow the first time it is used for each type `T`, because it has to produce the expression tree and compile it, but then it becomes very fast. This compared to the version that uses the `Activator.CreateInstance` that is slow every time :-)